# Spring session concurrency

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, session-management

I want to use spring security to handle session concurrency. I want prevent logging in of same accounts. What I've done so far is the authentication part by implementing `AuthenticationProvider`. I overrode `authenticate()` method and I think the authentication process is fine now. My next step is to add the session concurreny. I've added this in my spring xml:

```xml
<beans:bean id="loginAuthenticator" class="[...]" />

<sec:http auto-config='true'>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />  
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.do" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url='/home.do' always-use-default-target='true'/>
    <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.do"/>

    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" session-authentication-error-url="/login.do" invalid-session-url="/login.do">  
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />  
    </sec:session-management>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider ref='loginAuthenticator' />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

I've tried logging in same accounts but it was still able to pass through. Could you enlighten me to what am I missing? Is there something that I need to implement or extend? Is my xml configuration wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: log as requested

```
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 04, 2013 4:40:15 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
INFO : com.addressbook.controllers.LoginController - ----------> LoginController - displayLoginPage()
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> authenticate() - authenticating user credentials
INFO : com.addressbook.utils.HashService - ----------> finally block hashing function
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> username: testuser1
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> password: 6ca13d52ca70c883e0f0bb101e425a89e8624de51db2d2392593af6a84118090
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> user xml file path: C:\Users\jlim\addressbook\xml\users.xml
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> reached finally block fetchUsers: [com.addressbook.pojos.User@2061b97c, com.addressbook.pojos.User@6fd88c7f, com.
addressbook.pojos.User@71f01f36]
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> user exists?: true
INFO : com.addressbook.controllers.LoginController - ----------> LoginController - showHomePage()
INFO : com.addressbook.controllers.LoginController - ----------> LoginController - user from session: testuser1
INFO : com.addressbook.dao.impl.ContactDaoImpl - ----------> contacts xml file path: C:\Users\jlim\addressbook\xml\contacts.xml
INFO : com.addressbook.dao.impl.ContactDaoImpl - ----------> reached finally block fetchContactsFromXml(): [com.addressbook.pojos.Contact@32983d64, com.addressbook.pojos.Contact@28e68a
2f, com.addressbook.pojos.Contact@377a28a3]
INFO : com.addressbook.controllers.LoginController - ----------> LoginController - displayLoginPage()
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> authenticate() - authenticating user credentials
INFO : com.addressbook.utils.HashService - ----------> finally block hashing function
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> username: testuser1
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> password: 6ca13d52ca70c883e0f0bb101e425a89e8624de51db2d2392593af6a84118090
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> user xml file path: C:\Users\jlim\addressbook\xml\users.xml
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> reached finally block fetchUsers: [com.addressbook.pojos.User@5bdb1d55, com.addressbook.pojos.User@e62e690, com.a
ddressbook.pojos.User@7f0eff50]
INFO : com.addressbook.security.LoginAuthenticator - ----------> user exists?: true
INFO : com.addressbook.controllers.LoginController - ----------> LoginController - showHomePage()
INFO : com.addressbook.controllers.LoginController - ----------> LoginController - user from session: testuser1
INFO : com.addressbook.dao.impl.ContactDaoImpl - ----------> contacts xml file path: C:\Users\jlim\addressbook\xml\contacts.xml
INFO : com.addressbook.dao.impl.ContactDaoImpl - ----------> reached finally block fetchContactsFromXml(): [com.addressbook.pojos.Contact@2971bd51, com.addressbook.pojos.Contact@6a4426
18, com.addressbook.pojos.Contact@20212829]
```

Comment: Is `<sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />` good enough for you?

Comment: @Xaerxess, your suggestion is already in my xml yet it's not working :( please help.

Comment: Can you add `<debug />` to your config and post the output after logging on one account from two user agents?

Comment: @Xaerxess, I'm sorry sir I am lost, could you tell me where to put `<debug />` exactly? it keeps on popping errors.

Comment: It works in Spring Security >= 3.1, maybe you're using 3.0, aren't you?

Comment: In my pom.xml it says the version is 3.1.1 and in my xml config is a spring-security-3.1.xsd

Comment: Then you should just add `<sec:debug />` anywhere in your config (i.e. under `<beans:beans>`).

Comment: Hi sir, what I saw was only my custom logs. The logger is of type slf4j logger. does this logger works hand in hand with the `<sec:debug />` configuration? I am really sorry this discussion is getting long because of my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Yes, it should work. Just add log output (edit your question), it'll have some useful information.

Comment: I am afraid there are no logs sir. The only logs that I can see in the console are my custom logs. Does this mean that my program flow does not follow the spring security flow?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27543/discussion-between-xaerxess-and-oneb)

Comment: Sorry sir I cannot enter the chat room, I've been staring on the "Just a second" overlay for a quite a wile now.

Comment: OK, another way: can you add line log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG to your logger config (like described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html))?

Comment: Hello sir @Xaerxess, i was able to get the debug logs of spring security. Do you have an instant messenger where we could possibly continue our discussion. Thank you very much for helping me through all this up until now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the listener in your `web.xml`?:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Also, take a look at the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt) (version 3.2, but is the same in 3.x)